# React native post request with image

Tags: android, reactjs, post, fetch, native

I'm stuck for days on that, so i come here if someone has the kindess to help me. My probleme is that when I use fetch to post an image to my database with my body taking a formdata of my image with an image picker, it just gave me back that (Note that when i just use google chrome to test the .php , it work well) :

```
  <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" value=""/>

      <div>
          <button type="submit" name="fileToUpload">UPLOAD</button>
        </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

My fetch with the image :

```
   console.log( NewImg)
      const data = new FormData();
      const url = 'https://jaimeleshommes.online/pub.php?Token=' + await AsyncStorage.getItem('TokenProfile')
       data.append("name", 'fileToUpload');
       data.append("file_attachment", NewImg.base64);
      fetch(url,
        {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; ',
          },
        })
         .then((response) => response.text())
         .then((ResponseData) => {
           console.log(ResponseData)
       });
```

When i just change 'NewImg.base64' to 'NewImg', I just got Network error... Thanks a lot